# SQL outer apply not returning results I expect

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm not sure how to go about this, I think I should do a cross outter join here, but I'm not sure if there is a better way.

I have this broken query, which will not run because the first subquery returns 3 results instead of one, but by reading it you should see what I'm trying to accomplish

```
select top 1 [weight], dateofvisit from WeeklyVisits where PatientId in
(
select PatientId, StartDate, StartWeight from plans where PatientId in 
(select id from patients where clinicid=11 and id in
(select distinct(patientid) from plans))
) order by dateofvisit desc
```

I want to return 1 results for each patientid, the one result will be the newest dateofvisit.

weight, dateofvisit, patientid, startdate,visitdate

I'm thinking a cross outer join because of the where subqueries will not allow me to join these.

So I've at least attempted a cross outer join which runs with no errors, but it's not displaying only the patients in clinic id 11, it's not displaying the last result only and it is displaying null dates and weight. Nothing is working right here; but SQL isn't a very strong point for me.

```
select p.startdate, p.StartWeight, p.PatientId, x.DateOfVisit, x.[Weight]
from plans p 
outer apply(
select top 1 [Weight], [DateOfVisit] from WeeklyVisits w 
where p.PatientId=w.PatientId and [weight] is not null and DateOfVisit is not null and p.PatientId in (
select id from patients where clinicid=11 and id in
(select PatientId from plans))
)as x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from
(   select PatientId, StartDate, StartWeight, dateofvisit,
           row_number() over (partition by PatientId order by dateofvisit desc) as rownum
      from WeeklyVisits  
      join plans 
        on plans.PatientId = WeeklyVisits.PatientId 
      join patients 
        on patients.id = plans.id 
       and clinicid = 11 )
 where rownum = 1
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the over keyword and I'm getting an incorrect syntax on that keyword so I'm not sure how to debug it.

Comment: Post the version of SQL Server you are running (2205/2008 etc.) Some versions support it some don't

Comment: That was from memory - search it on msdn.  It might be row_number().  I do sql for living.  This is a good approach.

Comment: @mountaindweller, there was extra comma , try now